# iOS 9 not retaining animations on back to old screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue in my app in iOS 9. I have an animation on the first page of my app. It works fine for iOS 8 or earlier, but in iOS 9 phones when I go to next viewcontroller and come back to that viewcontroller animation stops. Here is my code.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:NO];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        btnStartLearning.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3,1.3);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```

Anyone knows where is the problem.
Thanks,

Comment: y u have [super viewWillAppear:NO]; instead of [super viewWillAppear:animated]; ?

Comment: It has no effect on that animation.

Comment: I want to know y you used NO in the super call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

```
btnStartLearning.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

before animation block

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:NO];
        btnStartLearning.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            btnStartLearning.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3,1.3);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
 }
```